# $i_1,i_2$ are ideals of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, is $[i_1,i_2]$ also an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, lie-algebras

> If $i_1$ and $i_2$ are ideals of $\mathfrak{g}$, I want to show that $[i_1,i_2]$ is also an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$.

This is how I proceed:

$[i_1,\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq i_1,[i_2,\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq i_2$

We want $[[i_1,i_2],\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq [i_1,i_2]$:

$$[[i_1,i_2],\mathfrak{g}]= -[\mathfrak{g},[i_1,i_2]]=[i_1,[i_2,\mathfrak{g}]]+ [i_2,[\mathfrak{g},i_1]]=[i_1,[i_2,\mathfrak{g}]]+ [i_2,-[i_1,\mathfrak{g}]]$$
$$\subseteq [i_1,i_2]+ [i_2,-i_1]=[i_1,i_2]+ [i_1,i_2]=2[i_1,i_2]=[i_1,i_2]$$

Is this acceptable?

Comment: You are working with ideals, not elements here. So $A+A$ is $A$, not $2A$. Remember that $A+A$ is the set of all elements of the form $a+b$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in A$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh yes, sorry, I guess I missed that because it was closed under scalars anyway

Comment: Use jacobi, $[x,[i_1,i_2]]+[i_2,[x,i_1]]+[i_1,[i_2,x]]=0$

Comment: @TsemoAristide I did, are you saying to use it in a different way?

Comment: The line with the factor $2$ looks strange. For characteristic $2$ this would imply $[i_1,i_2]+[i_1,i_2]=0=[i_1,i_2]$, which is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jacobi. You have to show that for every $i_1\in I_1, i_2\in I_2$ and $x\in {\cal G}$, $[x,[i_1,i_2]]\in [I_1,I_2]$. Jacobi implies that $[x,[i_1,i_2]]+[i_2,[x,i_1]]+[i_1,[i_2,x]]=0$, thus $[x,[i_1,i_2]] =-[i_2,[x,i_1]]-[i_1,[i_2,x]]$

$[x,i_1]\in I_1$ since $I_1$ is an ideal, thus $[i_2,[x,i_1]]\in [I_1,I_2]$

$[i_2,x]\in I_2$ since $I_2$ is an ideal, thus $[i_1,[i_2,x]]\in [I_1,I_2]$

Comment: I think that is precisely what I did, except instead of writing $\forall x\in \mathfrak{g}$, I just used $\mathfrak{g}$.